# Not able to create an ASP.NET website with visual studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, iis-7

I have installed ASP.NET along with my Visual Studio, but when I tried to create a website from `File-->New Website` and put Location as http and language as C# it throws an error. I have installed IIS manager 7 in the machine but when I check in Services.msc IISadmin is not listed, but I do have a directory C:\inetpub\wwwroot\

[image: This is the error shown when I try to create the website]

Comment: Did you try what the message said to try?

Comment: Sorry..., I did not know that we would have to configure the components separately, thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the umbrella 'IIS' is not enough. You have to go deeper into IIS in Windows Features and physically select everything that error dialog tells you to install.

Comment: Yes, I didn't check the features within the IIS from the windows features.., thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install those features as well.

If you're running Windows 7 Home Basic and Starter Editions, you may not get all of them as available options.

This will help: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-7-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/

Comment: I did a mistake.., I did not see the checkboxes within the IIS from Windows functions.., thank you :)

Comment: No probs! Make sure you upvote correct answers (as you can only accept one)

Answer (score 1):

check from the window features if iis components are all installed.